# Under/over approximation while summing int multiplied by double

Tags: c++, double, division

My code is supposed too evaluate the evolution of a sistem by a method of discretization of differential equations but all the data it needs to modify are integers which sum needs to be constant. The problem lies here,their sum diminishes. How can I try and solve this?

```
 mystruct Population {
      int T;
      int S;
      int R;
      int I;
    };
     
    std::vector<Population> result{p0_};
    int repetitions = 20 ;
    double gamma = 0.01 ;
    double beta = 0.02 ;
    for (int i = 1; i < repetitions; ++i) {
    auto const& prev = result.back();

 mystruct p;
      p.S = prev.S - (prev.I * prev.S) * beta;
      p.I = prev.I + (prev.I * prev.S) * beta -
              prev.I * gamma;
      p.R = prev.R + prev.I * gamma;
 result.push_back(p);

  }
```

This are the equations.

these are a couple examples of outputs,where T is supposed to be 50

> S = 47; I = 3; R =  0; T = 50
>
> S = 43; I = 5; R =  0; T = 48

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I'm sorry,what should I add?

Comment: With a reputation of 43, I am surprised you are not aware of a [mcve].

Comment: is this better?

Comment: `double gamma = 0.01 ; double beta = 0.02 ;` -- You're already in trouble.  These cannot be represented exactly in binary.  Why not use integers, i.e. use 1 and 2, and at the end, divide the results back by 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple. The multiplication to float/double auto-converts the integers to floating types. And converting floating types to integers has rounding errors: round-towards-zero is the default behavior.

If you simply want to ensure that sum remains constant while working with integers simply ensure the that numbers you add/subtract are integers and consistent.

```
   mystruct p;
   int tmpInt1 = (prev.I * prev.S) * par_.beta;
   int tmpInt2 = prev.I * par_.gamma;
   p.S = prev.S - tmpInt1;
   p.I = prev.I + tmpInt1 -tmpInt2;
   p.rec = prev.R + tmpInt2;
```

You might also prefer to use `round()` prior to double/float to int casting.

Edit: also, what's the difference between `.R` and `.rec`? You might have a member variable you forgot about.

Comment: Thank you, i modified my code before submitting it here but I didn't notice I left that rec,which should have been R !